# Can a software be developed based on a Juypter Notebook workflow?

Tags: python

I have a workflow process housed in a Jupyter Notebook that uses spaCy to parse text documents. The workflow process essentially reads a text file and returns all sentences containing the keywords provided by user (similar to Google search which returns hyperlinks instead) To use that workflow, a potential user then needs to have Python, Jupyter, spaCy and some other packages installed which might be a turn-off factor. Is it possible to build a standalone software based on that Jupyter Notebook workflow process so that all user needs is to install that software?

If yes, could you please give me some pointers how to go about that?

Thank you

Comment: see [Why is "Is it possible to:" a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)

Comment: @gnat, thanks for the information but I simply didn't know how else I could go about to ask the question due to the simple fact that I'm not a SE, nor a programmer, but just a Data Science student. What I was looking for is an answer **yes** or **no** where one can replicate a workflow process that is currently executing in Jupyter notebook. My thinking was that if a chef could answer a question from someone who barely knows how to cook rice with a rice cooker whether possible to cook rice in a clay pot, then a SE would be able to offer some good tips.to my seemingly silly question too.

Comment: It's probably possible, but it doesn't sound like much fun.

Comment: Isn't this the kind of problem that *containers* were invented to solve ?

Comment: Thanks, @HighPerformanceMark. That sounds interesting. Never heard of the terms so will have a look into that. Grateful for your pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can a software be developed based on a Juypter Notebook workflow?

Well since Juypter notebook workflows are software, yes!

Regardless of whatever turn-off factors here you have something that works. That proves that this problem is a computable one and that you have a formal definition of it's solution. The only question is how readable that definition is.

Easily 80% of my career has been essentially doing work like this. Some old code solves some old problem but now we want it solved in some new way. Sometimes it's as simple as we want the solution written in a new language. Sometimes we want it to work in a different system.

The biggest thing you have to do right now is clearly define why you don't just keep using the solution you already have. What new capabilities are you looking for? Being a code base that JavaScript programmers can maintain would be a new capability.

At this point you're ready to turn this over to one of us code monkeys who happens to speak both the old and the new language. They'll know they're done when the new stuff does what the old stuff did in this new way.

Key here is making sure the code monkey can run the old stuff on their dev box. That works so much faster than burying them in documents.

Comment: Even without knowledge in SE, I can intuitively understand and appreciate your logical discourse on my question. Now I know whom I would approach to if I want to convert my Jupyter workflow process into a standalone software for commercial purposes. Thanks, @candied_orange.